# A triple integral using spherical coordinates trick?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to calculate this integral.

$$\iiint_V (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)  dx  dy  dz$$

where $$V = {(x,y,z) : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ≤ R^2, y^2 + z^2 ≤ x^2, x ≥ 0}$$
It seems obvious that we need a change to spherical coordinates as we know that a sphere is given by the equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2$, where $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $R > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been asked but was closed, I still wanted to make a post to answer it, in my own way.
To calculate this triple integral, we should change the variables to spherical coordinates. When we see the conditions about this integral, a clever change is to set the $y$ and $z$ in $\theta$, and let the other, $x$, to $\phi$
$$ \large \begin{cases} x = \rho \cos \phi  \\ y = \rho \cos \theta \sin \phi
\\ z = \rho \sin \theta \sin \phi
\end{cases}.   
$$
To do this correctly, we will have to calculate the determinant of the Jacobian $J(\rho, \theta,\phi)$. 
I will not calculate this, but know that $dxdydz=\rho^2\sin(\phi) d\rho  d\phi d\theta$
.
Let's check our conditions, now.

1. As we know, the first condition $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq R^2$ will tell us to integrate from $0$ to $R$ for our $d\rho$
2. We can replace our spherical coordinates in $y^2 + z^2 \leq x^2$ to see what it will be.
   $$ \rho^2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi + \rho^2\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi \leq \rho^2\cos^2\phi $$
   Because $\rho > 0$,
   $$ \cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi + \sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi \leq \cos^2\phi $$
   With the Pythagorean Identity,
   $$ \sin^2\phi \leq \cos^2\phi $$
   For any $\phi \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $\cos^2\phi -\sin^2\phi = \cos 2\phi$,
   $$ \large \cos 2\phi \geq 0 $$
   And that is true if $\large\phi \in [0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$ or $\large [\frac{3\pi}{4}, \pi]$, as we know that $0\leq \phi \leq \pi$.
3. For the last condition, $x \geq 0$ means $\rho \cos \phi  \geq 0$, but $\rho$ is defined positive, so we must have, $\cos \phi  \geq 0$.
   This is only true if $\large 0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ (because again $0\leq \phi \leq \pi$).

If we regroup our conditions 2) and 3), we have that $\large\phi \in [0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$.
We don't have any conditions on $\theta$ so $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$.
Let's rewrite our integral properly,
\begin{align*}
\large \iiint_V (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)  dx  dy  dz  &= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\LARGE\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{R} \rho^2(\rho^2\sin\phi)d\rho  d\phi d\theta \\
\large \iiint_V (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)  dx  dy  dz  &= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\LARGE\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{R} \rho^4\sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta. 
\end{align*}
And calculate this integral,
\begin{align*} 
\large \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\LARGE\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{R} \rho^4\sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta &= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\LARGE\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{R^5}{5} \sin\phi   d\phi d\theta \\
\large \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\LARGE\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{R} \rho^4\sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta &= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{R^5}{5} [-\cos\phi]_0^{\LARGE\frac{\pi}{4}}  d\theta \\
\large \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\LARGE\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{R} \rho^4\sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta &= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{R^5}{5} (1 - \frac{\sqrt2}{2})  d\theta \\
\large \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\LARGE\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{R} \rho^4\sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta &= \large \pi \frac{R^5}{5} (2 - \sqrt2).
\end{align*}

So we finally have,
$$
\boxed{\LARGE \iiint_V (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)  dx  dy  dz = \LARGE \pi \frac{R^5}{5} (2 - \sqrt2)} .$$